# Magento2 : How to add <item> in XML <block> <arguments>

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I would like to update the following layout .xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="itemRenderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                    <item name="simple" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                    <item name="virtual" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/item/default</item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="item.image" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/view/image</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/product/image</item>
                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">itemImage</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

by adding

```
<item name="mytype" xsi:type="string">mytypeRenderer</item>
```

under 'itemRenderer'

I then define the xml file in my module :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument>
                    <item name="mytype" xsi:type="string" after="virtual">mytypeRenderer</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

but it is not working...

THank you for your help

EDIT 1 :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="itemRenderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="mytype" xsi:type="string">mytypeRenderer</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">mytypeRenderer</item>
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/checkout/minicart/item/default</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="itemRenderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="mytype" xsi:type="string">mytypeRenderer</item>
                               </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does not work... same result : none of the mytype items are displayed in minicart

Comment: Maybe it is due to the associated template definition... Please see my EDIT1